# IntelliJ: reorder methods by first usage

Tags: java, intellij-idea, methods, refactoring

`IntelliJ` provides a couple of ways to reorder method. It seems that there is one possibility missing, namely reordering methods by their usage. I'd like to have all private methods to be sorted in accordance with their first calling - method that is  called first should be first. Let me show example for clarity:

```
public void foo() {

bar();
foo();

}

private void foo() {}
private void bar() ()
```

In this example, `bar()` should go before `foo` because `bar` is executed before `foo`. Is that type of method ordering possible in `IntelliJ`   ?

Comment: You mean the first use of the method *textually* , right? Figuring out which method is *executed* first will require solving the halting problem.

Comment: Textually, of course.

Comment: afaik that's not possible: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/rearrange-code.html#create-matching-rules